# Api returns blob variable as null

Tags: java, spring, database, api, postman

Already created Rest Api in Spring Boot function which create new order with few variables and also with picture as a Blob and send it to the database.

And i it all works as it should, but right now when I'm trying get this picture as a response from database I'm getting this Blob as a null.

My Controller code is as shown below.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getallorders")
public List<OrderAllUsersResponse> getAllOrders() {

    List<OrderAllUsersResponse> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();

    List<OrderEntity> orders = orderRepostiory.findAllOrders();
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    for (int i=0; i < orders.size(); i++) {
        returnValue.add(modelMapper.map(orders.get(i), OrderAllUsersResponse.class));
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

My Repository code is as shown below.

---

```
public interface OrderRepostiory extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM 34671478_opionion.cargo", nativeQuery = true)
    List<OrderEntity> findAllOrders();
}
```

---

```
@Entity(name = "cargo")
public class OrderEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String orderId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String customer;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String loadingCompanyName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String loadingCity;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String loadingPostcode;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String dateOfLoading;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String unloadingCompanyName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String unloadingCity;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String unloadingPostcode;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String dateOfUnloading;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double nettoPrice;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double bruttoPrice;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String information;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean paymentStatus = false;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action= NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private CompanyEntity companyDetails;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "photo", columnDefinition="BLOB")
    private byte[] data;

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(String customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public String getLoadingCompanyName() {
        return loadingCompanyName;
    }

    public void setLoadingCompanyName(String loadingCompanyName) {
        this.loadingCompanyName = loadingCompanyName;
    }

    public String getLoadingCity() {
        return loadingCity;
    }

    public void setLoadingCity(String loadingCity) {
        this.loadingCity = loadingCity;
    }

    public String getLoadingPostcode() {
        return loadingPostcode;
    }

    public void setLoadingPostcode(String loadingPostcode) {
        this.loadingPostcode = loadingPostcode;
    }

    public String getDateOfLoading() {
        return dateOfLoading;
    }

    public void setDateOfLoading(String dateOfLoading) {
        this.dateOfLoading = dateOfLoading;
    }

    public String getUnloadingCompanyName() {
        return unloadingCompanyName;
    }

    public void setUnloadingCompanyName(String unloadingCompanyName) {
        this.unloadingCompanyName = unloadingCompanyName;
    }

    public String getUnloadingCity() {
        return unloadingCity;
    }

    public void setUnloadingCity(String unloadingCity) {
        this.unloadingCity = unloadingCity;
    }

    public String getUnloadingPostcode() {
        return unloadingPostcode;
    }

    public void setUnloadingPostcode(String unloadingPostcode) {
        this.unloadingPostcode = unloadingPostcode;
    }

    public String getDateOfUnloading() {
        return dateOfUnloading;
    }

    public void setDateOfUnloading(String dateOfUnloading) {
        this.dateOfUnloading = dateOfUnloading;
    }

    public Double getNettoPrice() {
        return nettoPrice;
    }

    public void setNettoPrice(Double nettoPrice) {
        this.nettoPrice = nettoPrice;
    }

    public Double getBruttoPrice() {
        return bruttoPrice;
    }

    public void setBruttoPrice(Double bruttoPrice) {
        this.bruttoPrice = bruttoPrice;
    }

    public CompanyEntity getCompanyDetails() {
        return companyDetails;
    }

    public void setCompanyDetails(CompanyEntity companyDetails) {
        this.companyDetails = companyDetails;
    }

    public String getInformation() {
        return information;
    }

    public void setInformation(String information) {
        this.information = information;
    }

    public Boolean getPaymentStatus() {
        return paymentStatus;
    }

    public void setPaymentStatus(Boolean paymentStatus) {
        this.paymentStatus = paymentStatus;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
}
```

Below I show you how response result like from Postman.

[image]

[image]

As u can see the variable 'photo' is as a null. How can i fix it to get it as a for example byte64string

Below is OrderAllUsersResponse class code:

[image]

Comment: Post your OrderAllUsersResponse class code.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/6rsid @ZakariaHossain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modelMapper's default mapping mechanism, your source (OrderEntity) and destination (OrderAllUsersResponse) objects should be similar to each other.

```
@Entity(name = "cargo")
public class OrderEntity implements Serializable {

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "photo", columnDefinition="BLOB")
    private byte[] data;

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class OrderAllUsersResponse {

        @JsonProperty("photo")
        private byte[] data;
    
        public byte[] getData() {
            return data;
        }
    
        public void setData(byte[] data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
  }
```

If the source field name is different from the destination field name then to define property mappings, you will use ModelMapper's TypeMap.

```
@Entity(name = "cargo")
public class OrderEntity implements Serializable {

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "photo", columnDefinition="BLOB")
    private byte[] data;

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class OrderAllUsersResponse {
        private byte[] photo;
    
        public byte[] getPhoto() {
            return photo;
        }
    
        public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
            this.photo = photo;
        }
  }
```

TypeMaping

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getallorders")
public List<OrderAllUsersResponse> getAllOrders() {
    List<OrderAllUsersResponse> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
    List<OrderEntity> orders = orderRepostiory.findAllOrders();

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    TypeMap<OrderEntity, OrderAllUsersResponse> propertyMapper = modelMapper.createTypeMap(OrderEntity.class, OrderAllUsersResponse.class);

    for (int i=0; i < orders.size(); i++) {
        propertyMapper.addMapping(OrderEntity::getData, OrderAllUsersResponse::setPhoto);
        returnValue.add(modelMapper.map(orders.get(i), OrderAllUsersResponse.class));
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```